Routing two Azure function apps to a single application gateway
I have two Azure function apps e.g. with function urls as: apis.azurewebsites.net and graphql.azurewebsites.net
However, only one function app is working with the application gateway. I have 2 of each listeners, backend settings, routing rules and backend pools setup to point to the relevant function app.
However, no matter what I try, I cannot get through to one of the function apps.
What am I missing? This is the current error message I am getting from one of the health probes:

The backend health status could not be retrieved. This happens when an NSG/UDR/Firewall on the application gateway subnet is blocking traffic on ports 65503-65534 in case of v1 SKU, and ports 65200-65535 in case of the v2 SKU or if the FQDN configured in the backend pool could not be resolved to an IP address. To learn more visit - https://aka.ms/UnknownBackendHealth.

I am also unsure how hitting the single public IP of the application gateway will be able to tell which function app backend I am trying to make a request to.
Any help would be appreciated.

This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#other-reasons

I have tried the tips mentioned there already, but still returns the unknown error.

Are you trying to access two Function apps with the same Application Gateway IP using round robin? or multisite, if you are using multisite, could you please share screenshots of the configuration for two listeners, two backend settings, and two routing rules for further clarification?

Refer  the link 1 & Link2 for multisite configurations.

Yes I realised I can use Host header in the request to determine which listener to use

Can you please share some screenshots from the App Gw configuration?
